# excel hyperlink via gui vs hyperlink function

Tags: microsoft-excel

excel 2010,

I try to understand  the difference between

`insert hyperlink via gui` vs `insert hyperlink via hyperlink function`.

I try to link to external files (a lot of photo). I think `hyperlink function` is better, because it shows the content of links in formula box. So I believe it won't change later.

`gui method` is more easier to use. But it's a black box.

**via gui**:

image1:

[image]

image2:

[image]

vs

**insert hyperlink via hyperlink**:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Interesting question. I can show you the difference, but I can only guess the difference is for backward compatibility.

First create a simple test file and then [use this trick to view the xml structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8984254/how-to-view-the-xml-form-of-an-excel-file).

[image]

Navigate and open the sheet where the data is contained (my cyan highlight). Notice the difference between row 1 (gui hyperlink, yellow highlight) and row 2 (formula hyperlink, green highlight)

[image]

Excel seems to know how to create the hyperlink by referencing a couple of other files shown with my magenta highlights:

[image]

[image]

At this point, you can draw your own conclusions and add a new answer, or comment.