# Excel Hyperlink Function not Feature tooltip

Tags: microsoft-excel, hyperlink

Good morning,

I use Pentaho Report Designer for writing reports. I can make tooltips for PDF and HTML reports. I have found a way to pass the hyperlink function (=hyperlink(link_location,[Friendly_name])) from Pentaho Report Designer to Excel. The limitation I have found is in Excel when using the hyperlink function, there is no way to pass a tooltip (MS Excel calls it screentip). The Links feature in Excel allows screentips but the hyperlink function does not. Does anyone know how to get screentips to show on the hyperlink function in Excel?

Thank you

Comment: Maybe this could shed some light: https://superuser.com/questions/1628013/excel-hyperlink-via-gui-vs-hyperlink-function. Basically to invoke the screentip you'll have to create a "gui" hyperlink instead of the formula hyperlink. Hopefully that can be done with your program.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I apologize. When I said Links feature in Excel, I am referring to the "gui" hyperlink option. This I cannot do but I can do the Excel function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bit of a hack, but would get the job done (for most URLs). Use the # sign ([URI fragment identifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URI_fragment)) to add tooltip text to the URL in the hyperlink formula, since Excel will show the hyperlink function URL as a tooltip. In most cases, the webserver/your browser will just ignore everything after the hash (unless your tooltip text also happens to be a valid and matching heading or HTML subordinate, in which case your browser with jump to said heading). You can use alt+enter to put line feed characters before and after your "hacked tooltip" text like this:

[image]

Comment: Is there a hack for trying to reference the same cell in Excel? This works =HYPERLINK("#sheet0!A1","Test")  but this does not work =HYPERLINK("#sheet0!A1#' ToolTip Workaround'","Test")

Comment: Unfortunately this fragment identifier hack only seems to work with URLs and not with workbook or cell references. The only way I can see to include some version of tooltip is a) insert the tooltip into the hyperlink using VBA coding b) insert a note or comment in cell as it will pop-up on hover too or c) put a comment in the formula with something like `=HYPERLINK(...)&T(N("Your comment here"))`

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Unfortunately, Pentaho Report Designer to my knowledge doesn't allow VBA. You still were able to provide a working solution for another workaround :).

Comment: So I'm not familiar with Pentaho at all. Out of pure curiosity, care to explain your workflow a bit? Where does your raw data come from? Do you generate excel reports? Can Pentaho actually generate formulae inside the excel report for you? Why tooltips? Why not just put the text info in a neighboring cell?

Comment: My raw data comes from a JDBC connection. I can generate reports into one sheet/multiple sheets. The data from multiple sheets can come from one query with grouped data or from multiple subreports depending on the report design. You can put some Excel formulas in the report, but I prefer doing everything in SQL. You can freeze rows/columns like View Freeze in Excel. So far, I have not been able to replicate data validation, comments, or the gui hyperlink feature (all have tooltips). The tooltip project is to reduce the fields in the report while guiding users on what to do.